# property storage cannot find expected per-thread storage data

Tags: ios, multithreading

When I call [[AVQueuePlayer alloc]init] happen to error  like this

```
Fatal Exception NSInternalInconsistencyException
property storage cannot find expected per-thread storage data
```

What's the problem?

I just call above method for allocate AVQueuePlayer,

Comment: `AVQueuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc]init];` .. or if you created object of `AVQueuePlayer` in .h file then `self.yourObjectname = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc]init];`